# Rust error E0495 using split_at_mut in a closure

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm encountering an *"error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements"* with this simple function:

```
fn assign_split_at_mut<'a, 'b, T>(s: &'b mut &'a mut [T], mid: usize) -> &'a mut [T] {
    let (x, y) = (*s: &'a mut [T]).split_at_mut(mid);
    *s = y;
    x
}
```

I wrote a [playpen example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%23![feature%28type_ascription%29]%0A%0Afn%20assign_split_at_mut%3C%27a%2C%27b%2CT%3E%28s%3A%20%26%27b%20mut%20%26%27a%20mut%20[T]%2C%20mid%3A%20usize%29%20-%3E%20%26%27a%20mut%20[T]%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20%28x%2Cy%29%20%3D%20%28*s%20%3A%20%26%27a%20mut%20[T]%29.split_at_mut%3A%3A%3C%27a%3E%28mid%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20*s%20%3D%20y%3B%0A%20%20%20%20x%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F*%0Afn%20assign_split_at_mut_unsafe%3C%27a%2CT%3E%28s%3A%20%26mut%20%26%27a%20mut%20[T]%2C%20mid%3A%20usize%29%20-%3E%20%26%27a%20mut%20[T]%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20len%20%3D%20%28*s%3A%20%26%27a%20mut%20[T]%29.len%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20ptr%20%3D%20%28*s%3A%20%26%27a%20mut%20[T]%29.as_mut_ptr%28%29%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20unsafe%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20use%20std%3A%3Aslice%3A%3Afrom_raw_parts_mut%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20assert!%28mid%20%3C%3D%20len%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20*s%3A%20%26%27a%20mut%20[T]%20%3D%20from_raw_parts_mut%28ptr.offset%28mid%20as%20isize%29%2C%20len%20-%20mid%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20from_raw_parts_mut%28ptr%2C%20mid%29%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A*%2F%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22Hello%20world!%22%29%3B%0A%7D&version=nightly&backtrace=0) including this `unsafe` variant of `split_at_mut` that does work.

```
fn assign_split_at_mut_unsafe<'a, T>(s: &mut &'a mut [T], mid: usize) -> &'a mut [T] {
    let len = (*s: &'a mut [T]).len();
    let ptr = (*s: &'a mut [T]).as_mut_ptr();

    unsafe {
        use std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut;
        assert!(mid <= len);
        *s: &'a mut [T] = from_raw_parts_mut(ptr.offset(mid as isize), len - mid);
        from_raw_parts_mut(ptr, mid)
    }
}
```

In fact, I want to write roughly this:

```
pub fn slice_header<'a>(&'static self, mut header: &'a mut [u8])
  -> MyResult<HeaderRefs<'a>>
{
    // ...
    let take = |l: usize| -> &'a mut [u8] {
        let (x,y) = header.split_at_mut(l);
        header = y;  x
    };
    let hr = HeaderRefs {
        params: self,
        alpha: array_mut_ref![take(32),0,32],
        gamma: array_mut_ref![take(16),32,16],
        beta: take(self.beta_length as usize),
        surb_log: take(self.surblog_length as usize),
        surb: take(self.surb_length()),
    };
    // ...
    Ok(hr)
}
```

I believe it would work fine if I simply wrote out a bunch of

```
let (alpha,header) = header.split_at_mut(32);
let (gamma,header) = header.split_at_mut(16);
// ...
```

Maybe it'd work if I put them into an array.  I cannot get it to work with a closure, which would look much cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a borrowing issue:

```
fn assign_split_at_mut<'a, 'b, T>(s: &'b mut &'a mut [T], mid: usize) -> &'a mut [T] {
    let (x, y) = (*s: &'a mut [T]).split_at_mut(mid);
    *s = y;
    x
}
```

Specifically, `split_at_mut` borrows `s`, so you cannot *also* assign to `s` while it is borrowed.

To understand the issue, imagine that we were talking about vectors here, with `s: &mut Vec<T>`: you could first borrow a slice from the `Vec` and then use `s` to mutate it.

This is why Rust specifies that the *whole access path* is borrowed, not just the leaf.

---

Okay, so what now?

As mentioned by @nox, the solution is to "dance":

- move the ownership of `&'a mut [T]` out of `s` to a local variable
- borrow this local variable
- assign to `s`

This way, the borrow checker is appeased since it knows that modifying `s` cannot affect the local variable and its borrows.

There are various ways to move the ownership out of `&mut X` depending on the situation, some common ways are:

- `std::mem::replace`,
- `std::mem::swap`,
- `Option::take` if `X` is an `Option`,
- ...

In your case, `replace` is the simpler. And the solution provided by @nox is rather simple:

```
fn reserve<'heap, T>(heap: &mut &'heap mut [T], len: usize) -> &'heap mut [T] {
    let tmp: &'heap mut [T] = ::std::mem::replace(&mut *heap, &mut []);
    let (reserved, tmp) = tmp.split_at_mut(len);
    *heap = tmp;
    reserved
}
```

Comment: I'll give this best answer just for "dance".  ;)

Comment: @JeffBurdges: [Quote of the week 166](https://this-week-in-rust.org/blog/2017/01/24/this-week-in-rust-166/): *Yeah, it's like learning to dance when your partner (borrow checker) already knows all the steps. When you're just getting started, you step on their toes a lot, but over time you get the motions down. Eventually, you can start to anticipate their movements and start to appreciate the music as part of the dance, instead of just concentrating on getting your feet in the right place.*

Answer (score 0):

An IRC user [nox](https://github.com/nox) provided a clean answer by using `mem::replace` to move the `&mut [T]` that needs mutation out of the way first :

```
fn reserve<'heap, T>(heap: &mut &'heap mut [T], len: usize) -> &'heap mut [T] {
    let tmp: &'heap mut [T] = ::std::mem::replace(&mut *heap, &mut []);
    let (reserved, tmp) = tmp.split_at_mut(len);
    *heap = tmp;
    reserved
}
```

Comment: In face nox's suggestion lacked the type annotation on `tmp`.  I added it out of unnecessary paranoia.